# Audio not playing when ball enters the trigger

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have a game like the Rooltheball in unitys tutorials, and i want to play a sound when my ball hits the peaks, the thing is that i already tried everything, i basicly added a audioListener in my mainCamera, and added a audioSource and audioClip in the gameobject i want to detect the trigger, **here is the code i did:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
[RequireComponent(typeof(AudioSource))]
public class colisaoPicos : MonoBehaviour {



Manager gameManager;
    public AudioClip impact;
    private AudioSource audio;


    void Start()
    {
        gameManager = GameObject.Find ("GameController").GetComponent<Manager> ();
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider c)
    {
        if (c.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
            AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint (impact, transform.position);
            gameManager.LifeDown();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the `colisaoPicos` script attached to? Are you sure that `OnTriggerEnter` is being called at-all?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to add an audiosource on the ball, and make it play the clip each time you enter the trigger.

Just make the audio variable public, and drag the AudioSource into it in the inspector.

Second, but in my book, and uglier solution would be to make a gameobject spesifically for that purpose. Then put the gameobject at the spot, and play the sound.

But, as programmer said, you should check the trigger. Remember, one of the Game Objects has to contain a Rigidbody. (Is Kinematic can be active tho)

Answer (score 0):

As my experience, the following code is always working:

```
public AudioSource soundToPlay;

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider c)
{
    if (c.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
        soundToPlay.Play ();
    }
}
```

Do not try to use playOneShot, or play clip. Error happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will play the sound once if `Trigger` function is working in your case and do add `AudioListener` component with the `trigger` gameobject.

```
 using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
[RequireComponent(typeof(AudioSource))]
public class colisaoPicos : MonoBehaviour {



Manager gameManager;
    public AudioClip impact;
    private AudioSource audio;

void Start()
{
audio=GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    gameManager = GameObject.Find ("GameController").GetComponent<Manager();
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider c)
{
    if (c.gameObject.tag == "Player") {


audio.PlayOneShoot(impact);
        gameManager.LifeDown();
    }
}
```

}